# PHP debugging or performance Hook

Tags: php

In an interpreted language like PHP it is possible in theory to set up some sort of callback function that would be run indiscriminately after every line of code.  I am wondering if such a thing exists in PHP or if such a thing could be accomplished in any way?  Such a feature could be useful for diagnostics or performance tests.  Does anyone know of such a mechanism in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with that but you can check out zend-studio and xdebug